# How to make Facebook log out from my application

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook log in to login into my application.All the application was working good

but the user clicks on logout button in my application the user will be logout from my

application but the facebook account of loggedin user will not be logout from Facebook

application.when user logout from my application automatically user will be logout from the

facebook application also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your app is structured, but it is possible to log a user out of FB(or log them in, for that matter) using the JavaScript SDK.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/